CTRL-L in whole line completion
In insert mode completion (:help ins-completion), usually Ctrl L has the function of Add one character from the current match. However, for whole line completion, for some reason Ctrl-L is supposed to act the same as Ctrl P (as is explained in :help compl-whole-line). I don't understand this choice and would like to use the usual Ctrl L.
How can I perform this map?
For example, when one's cursor is on the word f, and one performs completion by <C-n> (or any other insert mode completion except whole-line completion), if one finds the following list of matches in the popup menu foo, foo1, foobar, foreach, then <C-l> would insert the next character in the first match. The first match here is foo, so <C-l> inserts the following character which would be 'o', and again, yields 'o' again (now that the search string becomes foo, the foreach option disappears in the popup menu).

That looks like an oversight when whole line completion was implemented. Now it is too late to change

@ChristianBrabandt Ohh hmmm. So you don't think there is any vimscript function today that allows us to get the usual  binding? If none such exists, what would you think to be a good API, I may be motivated to try implement this some time.

If you want to copy one character from the previous line you can use Ctrl Y.
You could of course map it to Ctrl L:
inoremap <C-l> <C-y>

Remark: Ctrl E copy one character from the next line.

Hmm that's not quite the <C-l> behaviour; in insert-mode completion, <C-l> adds the next character from the matches in the popup menu, rather than from the lines above or beneath the cursor.

Thanks for the feedback! Could you precise what do you means by usually (which program has such behavior)? Could you precise what is the behavior that you are looking for (I believe an example would help)?

For example, when one's cursor is on the word f, and one performs completion by <C-n> (or any other insert mode completion except whole-line completion), if one finds the following list of matches in the popup menu foo, foo1, foobar, foreach, then <C-l> would insert the next character in the first match. The first match here is foo, so <C-l> inserts the following character which would be 'o', and again, yields 'o' again (now that the search string becomes foo, the foreach option disappears in the popup menu).

@user22476690 I edited your question to include your comment.
